# Compiler shows undefined structure error while declaring a class

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, turbo-c++

Error message:

[image: 1980s screenshot of the problem]

[Link to full program](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7vXh8PnLFtJY0tJUzdNNG16Skk/view?usp=drivesdk)

```
class AddressBook
{
private:   
char firstname[20];
char lastname[20];
char no[15];

class adrs
{
public:
char postal[100];
char pincode[7];
friend void say();
friend void Add();
friend void Edit();
friend void View(int);
}address;
char dob[11];
char email[50];

public:
friend void say();
void sort(AddressBook []);
void NumberSort(AddressBook []);
void Add(void);
void Delete(AddressBook [], int pos);
void Edit();
void LinearSearch(AddressBook [], char a[]);
friend void ViewAll();
void View(int);
void FetchContact();
};
```

This is the declaration of a class for a contact-book program.

```
 void sort(AddressBook []);
 void NumberSort(AddressBook []); 
 void Delete(AddressBook [], int pos); 
 void LinearSearch(AddressBook [], char a[]);
```

These lines in the above declaration shows up as an error in TurboC++ compiler. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Would you paste the error info to the question? You mentioned undefined struct error while declaring a class. I don't see the struct in your code?

Comment: Having those functions as member functions doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer I don't see one too. That's the problem.

Comment: Please do yourself a favor and indent your code.

Comment: Do you know that TurboC++ is at least 20 years old? You would be better off with a more modern compiler/IDE

Comment: @Rakete1111 They force us to use Turboc++ in school.

Comment: @JohnSmith just curious: which school is it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude member functions is not much of an issue. I covered that part. This undefined structure error is the problem.

Comment: Please elaborate your question and maybe post a [MCVE]. My compiler accepts the `class AddressBook` declaration as well as the other declarations you mention in your question. What is the __exact error message__ and at which line __exactly__  does it occur?

Comment: I was just commenting on the design. We still need to see those errors though, and preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (where you mark out with comments where the errors are). Please edit your question to include that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude link added. By the way, this is just a part of the code.

Comment: @JohnSmith you show just a part of the code. Maybe that's why it compiles fine here. Please make a [MCVE]. This requires some work, but without that it's hard to help. There is nothing obviously wrong in the code you show in your question. The problem probably comes from the part of the code you didn't show.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I've added a link to the program. Can you help me now?

Comment: The full code you provide in the link doesn't have line breaks, so it's unusable for us. But anyway I've managed to make a [MCVE] for yoou, see my answer below.

Comment: Independently of the compile error: the design of your program looks rather flawed as far as I can see.

Comment: @MichaelWalz oh. Ok. Thank you so much for making a minimal example for me!

Comment: @MichaelWalz the assignment we were given was to convert a program written with structures to classes... That's why it looks like that...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As you were not able to produce minimal example, I did it for you:

```
class AddressBook
{
  void sort(AddressBook[]);
};
```

This declaration compiles fine on a modern compiler but not on Turbo C++.
You can call this a compiler bug.

There are two options:

- you rethink your program and write it another way
- you use a modern C++ compiler

Changing school would be another valuable option.

Comment: Oh. K. Thanks a lot... Any idea why that doesn't work on TurboC++?

Comment: @JohnSmith probably because it's an antique, non conforming compiler.

Comment: @JohnSmith Probably because _it predates even the oldest version of standard C++_. That is, it was programmed and distributed _before standard C++ existed_ and lacks some features of C++ as a result. This is really why you shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ when an array is passed as an argument, its initial address is passed to formal parameter. With the help of this technique the code can be written as follows

```
 void sort(AddressBook*);
 void NumberSort(AddressBook*); 
 void Delete(AddressBook*, int pos); 
 void LinearSearch(AddressBook*, char a[]);
```

I have implemented the same thing for my problem and it just worked.

Comment: True, but not really the point of the question, because that's already what the code was doing (`T[]` in a function param is exactly `T*`) - the key salient point is that the `T[]` form wasn't supported for whatever reason.